# What's the best OS for Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am gonna develop a fiber optic network on Omnet++ to evaluate the performance. How well does this software work on OS MAVERICKS?  I heard that it doesn't works well on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather subjective question. Probably that's why it is down-voted. My personal preference as a core developer:
- Linux
- Mac OS X
- Windows

OMNeT++ itself works exactly the same way on all platforms, but some platforms have issues with certain external components OMNeT++ is using.

- Windows: slow compile times (compared to Linux/Mac OS X because of GCC and the way NTFS handles small files.) Otherwise everything works as expected.
- Mac OS X: Tcl/Tk is no longer maintained by Apple, so you may see visual glitches in Tkenv here and there (but all functionality is available). GDB is no longer bundled in the Mac OS command line tools download from Apple. You have to install and digitally sign GDB manually. You have to do this only once, though...